# Am I really this stupid : this = 0x7ffffffe

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a very simple class stub - i just started making it:

```
class CJSScript
{
public:
    CJSScript(std::string scriptfile);
    ~CJSScript(void);
private:
    std::string scriptname;
};
CJSScript::CJSScript(std::string scriptfile)
{
    size_t found = scriptfile.find_last_of("/\\");
    scriptname = scriptfile.substr(found+1);
    printf("should load %s now...", scriptname);

}
```

however in that constructor i get an exception, `this` apparently is set to `0x7ffffffe`

main program is

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CJSScript* test=new CJSScript("./script/test.js");
  system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

what the hell is going on. i thought i had basics behind me a long time ago but this is a compromitation. of me or the compiler :)

debugger dump :

```
Win32Project3.exe!_output_l(_iobuf * stream, const char * format, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo, char * argptr) Line 1649    C++
Win32Project3.exe!printf(const char * format, ...) Line 62  C
Win32Project3.exe!CJSScript::CJSScript(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > scriptfile) Line 11 C++
Win32Project3.exe!wmain(int argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 38 C++
Win32Project3.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 240  C
```

Comment: Might be a calling-convention related bug. Using the wrong calling convention on something can yield *very* bizarre side-effects.

Comment: What exactly is the exception you get?

Comment: `printf` comes from C and expects a `const char*` for strings, not an `std::string`

Comment: @DyP Put this in an answer, I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` doesn't know how to deal with `string` objects.  You need to pass a `const char*`:

```
 printf("should load %s now...", scriptname.c_str());
```

This is an issue of type safety.  For this reason, among others, I prefer using streams.

```
cout << "should load " << scriptname << " now...";
```

Comment: oh. im not used to using `printf` i prefer `cout` :P so, this in constructor SHOULD be `0x7ffffffe` ? :D thx, will accept

Comment: Since your'e passing a `string` to `printf`, but `printf` is treating it like a `const char*`, there is undoubtedly something going on in `printf` that evokes Undefined Behavior.  If that's so, then sure -- it could set `this` to `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: @n00b: `this` can be one of many values in a well defined program, possibly including that exact bit pattern. It will be the address returned by the allocator called from the `new` expression and is out of your control. In this case, because you have undefined behavior it might have been overridden and it might hold any random value.